# alternative spawn() method in gevent-socketio

Tags: python, gevent-socketio

I use gevent-socketio in project. I need use `gevent.spawn()` method with function which listen redis queue. It not works cause `spawn()` waiting end of work function. 
Are there any alternative `spawn()` method in gevent-socketio?